# Using web.config files to rewrite for my program

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am looking for a way to use the URL Rewrite module to make the URLs for my program look cleaner.

I have been looking into IIS rewrite for a while now and whenever I get to the point where I think I understand it, nothing works.

I have this layout for my program.

etreecycle.co.uk/
- This has nothing to do with my program, this is a store for another project. (Wordpress)

etreecycle.co.uk/websites/MPW/
- My program is installed here.

etreecycle.co.uk/websites/MPW/index.php
- I want the first section of the domain to be put here, for example.

etreecycle.co.uk/websites/MPW/index.php?page=posts&action=1234
- I want this url to look like this: 
etreecycle.co.uk/websites/MPW/post/1234

I also have an index.php in the directory etreecycle.co.uk/websites/MPW/admin/

This should take the same layout.

For example;
etreecycle.co.uk/websites/MPW/admin/?page=settings&action=save
- should look like;
etreecycle.co.uk/websites/MPW/admin/settings/save

Can anyone help me achieve this with IIS URL Rewrite? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
                <rule name="home" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^settings/(\S+)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="admin/?page=settings&amp;action={R:1}" />
                </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: The program is hosted in a subdirectory, so should it be {R:1} or {R:4}?

Comment: Also, what happens if I don't have an action defined?

Comment: {R:1} means the first matching value in the regular expression. So it should still be R:1 in a sub directory. If you don't have an action, the pattern won't match, and the rewrite rule will be ignored. You may create another rule to map just "page=settings"

Comment: Can I place this within a web.config file within /websites/MPW?

Comment: Yes this has to be placed in web.config in the folder where the rewrite takes place. Also try putting it in the web.config in the admin folder and remove the "admin/" reference in the rule. I don't have an IIS to test at the moment but one of the settings should work.

Comment: The settings are being overwritten by wordpress. See here: http://etreecycle.co.uk/websites/MPW/admin/settings/test

Comment: Your question mentioned nothing about Wordpress. There's a chance that IIS has performed the redirect correctly but Wordpress took over and did a header redirect. Use Firebug and persist the view to see how 302 redirects are thrown.

Comment: I do mention that I have wordpress installed in the root. What is firebug?

Comment: Firebug is similar to the Developer Tools view in your Firefox or Chrome browser. Sorry I don't want to spend any more time on this knowing how Wordpress makes everything unnecessarily complicated.